# Manually / adjusting order of edge and path

Tags: graphviz, diagrammer

In the diagram below, I'm looking to have the dashed path/edge going through the middle of the diagram (and therefore the A -> C -> D path will be at the bottom).

I've spent about 2 hours trying to figure this out, including drawing additional paths using "edge [style="invis"]," but to no avail.

Can someone please assist?

```
DiagrammeR::grViz("digraph {

graph [layout = dot, rankdir = LR]

node [shape = rectangle]        
rec1 [label = 'A']
rec2 [label = 'B']
rec3 [label = 'C']
rec4 [label = 'D']

rec1 -> rec2 
rec1 -> rec3 
rec1 -> rec4 [style = dashed]
rec2 -> rec4 
rec3 -> rec4  
}"
)
```

[image]

Comment: "B" above, "C" below, and "A" and "D" in-the-middle?

Comment: Correct. That is what I'm hoping to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- changed **rankdir**
- used **rank=** to create 3 ranks
- used **nodesep** to spread *A -> D*

```
digraph {
// TB rankdir makes things easier
graph [layout = dot ] 
graph [nodesep=.9] // spread nodes on same rank
node [shape = rectangle]

{rank=source
  rec2 [label = "B"]
}
{rank=same
  rec1 [label = "A"]
  rec4 [label = "D"]
}
{ rank=sink
  rec3 [label = "C"]
}
rec1 -> rec2 
rec1 -> rec3 
rec1 -> rec4 [style = dashed]
rec2 -> rec4 
rec3 -> rec4  
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Very clever solution. I would have not figured that out on my own without many, many hours invested,